# systemd-resolved does not access zeroconf DNS server

Tags: dns, systemd, networkmanager

I am trying to connect to a wifi network and use the dns server provided in the local network.
Wifi works fine, but I cannot get DNS name resolution.
I am using NetworkManager and systemd-resolved.
The system is up-to-date archlinux.
The conf-Files of the services are empty, i.e. no special settings.
Does anyone see the problem or could give me advice what to try?

The DNS server (..0.1-server in the local network) is 172.17.0.1 (all the other devices, that manage to get a connection also say that they use this server as dns )

Update: it might not be DNS. Could it be that the other devices just have fallback DNS servers configured?
Systemd-resolved just doesn’t use the fallback.
However, just setting a public DNS like 8.8.4.4 is not a solution as the connection is unstable, as you can see by the long ping times below.

Sorry, I am not an expert. I tried for hours and googled all the error messages, but could not figure it out.

I tried to use dig to access it
I provided lots of information below
I also tried to set DNS to 8.8.8.8, but the connection seems to be slow and unstable.
Sometimes, I got a DNS response (with dig for example) but not stable to be usable
With windows and ios, this WIFI and DNS works fine-.

Here is the symptom: no name resolution.
Ping on an ip works.

```
~$ ping google.de
ping: google.de: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Here is more information that might help

```
:~$ sudo nmap -sU 172.17.0.1
[sudo] password for konrad: 
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-19 09:47 CEST
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
Host is up (0.0000090s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed udp ports (port-unreach)
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
5353/udp open|filtered zeroconf
5355/udp open|filtered llmnr

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.38 seconds


:~$ dig @172.17.0.1 google.de -p 5353
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#5353: timed out
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#5353: timed out
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#5353: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16 <<>> @172.17.0.1 google.de -p 5353
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached




● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-07-19 09:41:07 CEST; 1min 48s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 8432 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9352)
     Memory: 3.0M
        CPU: 183ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─8432 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Jul 19 09:41:26 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 172.17.0.1.
Jul 19 09:41:31 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 172.17.0.1.
Jul 19 09:41:31 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 172.17.0.1.
Jul 19 09:41:36 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 172.17.0.1.
Jul 19 09:41:36 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 172.17.0.1.
Jul 19 09:41:42 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: wlan0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Jul 19 09:41:42 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: wlan0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Jul 19 09:41:43 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: Switching to fallback DNS server 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com.
Jul 19 09:42:05 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: enp0s29u1u3: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Jul 19 09:42:05 thebeast systemd-resolved[8432]: enp0s29u1u3: Bus client set DNS server list to: 172.20.10.1


● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-07-19 09:38:50 CEST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 8213 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9352)
     Memory: 10.4M
        CPU: 715ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─8213 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4450] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4452] device (wlan0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4458] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4547] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed new lease, address=172.17.5.78
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4550] policy: set 'Gast' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4703] device (wlan0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4729] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4731] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4734] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jul 19 09:46:28 thebeast NetworkManager[8213]: <info>  [1689752788.4740] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.


:~$ sudo ss -pan 'sport = 53'
Netid        State         Recv-Q         Send-Q                 Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port        Process                                            
udp          UNCONN        0              0                         127.0.0.54:53                        0.0.0.0:*            users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=8432,fd=22))        
udp          UNCONN        0              0                      127.0.0.53%lo:53                        0.0.0.0:*            users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=8432,fd=20))        
tcp          LISTEN        0              4096                   127.0.0.53%lo:53                        0.0.0.0:*            users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=8432,fd=21))        
tcp          LISTEN        0              4096                      127.0.0.54:53                        0.0.0.0:*            users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=8432,fd=23)) 


:~$ resolvectl 
Global
           Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
    resolv.conf mode: stub
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 8.8.8.8#dns.google 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
                      2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google

Link 2 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (wlan0)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv4 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 172.17.0.1
       DNS Servers: 172.17.0.1

Link 6 (docker0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 8 (wwp0s20u8c2i12)
    Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv6 mDNS/IPv6
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

All other devices (Windows, phones, iOS) use this DNS server 172.17.0.1 and get DNS resolved.

The Google public DNS can be pinged, but it is not reliable.

```
$ ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=1060 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=504 ms
```

Connection on port 53 is not responding

```
~$ dig @172.17.0.1 google.de
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 172.17.0.1#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16 <<>> @172.17.0.1 google.de
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached
```

It seems that port 53 is not available on the DNS server

```
:~$ sudo nmap -sX 172.17.0.1
[sudo] password for konrad: 
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-19 20:09 CEST
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT   STATE         SERVICE
22/tcp open|filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.29 seconds

:~$ sudo nmap -A -p 53 172.17.0.1
[sudo] password for konrad: 
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-19 20:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
Host is up (0.000056s latency).

PORT   STATE  SERVICE VERSION
53/tcp closed domain
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.83 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as a "zeroconf DNS server" – port 5353 is for multicast DNS which is by design serverless. mDNS nodes only answer queries for their own names (almost always `*.local` names) – they do not act as recursive resolvers for general DNS. The same applies to LLMNR on 5355.

The actual DNS service that would be provided by the network is discovered via DHCP and always runs on port 53 (UDP and usually also TCP). Use `dig` *without* the `-p` parameter to access it.

(While technically zeroconf has a mechanism for discovering unicast DNS servers, literally nobody uses it, and the server would still be running on port 53 regardless.)

According to your scan, the server isn't listening on the UDP port and according to system logs it's not listening on TCP 53 either.

If the server responds to ping but not to DNS queries, it's misconfigured.

Comment: Thank you. I added more information at the bottom and this remark: it might not be DNS. Could it be that the other devices just have fallback DNS servers configured?
Systemd-resolved just doesn’t use the fallback. 
However, just setting a public DNS like 8.8.4.4 is not a solution as the connection is unstable, as you can see by the long ping times.  Do you have any further advice?